# type_info compiler bug in MSVC?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, types, clang

So I've got this code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

void thing(char thing[2], int thing2) {

}

void thing2(char* thing, int thing2) {

}

template <typename T, typename U>
struct are_types_same {
    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept { return false; }
};

template <typename T>
struct are_types_same<T, T> {
    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept { return true; }
};

int main() {
    const std::type_info& info = typeid(thing);
    const std::type_info& info2 = typeid(thing2);

    std::cout << "typeid: " << (info == info2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "are_types_same: " << are_types_same<decltype(thing), decltype(thing2)>{} << '\n';
}
```

I was surprised to see that when comparing the type infos of the types in MSVC (x86, v19.32), the comparison yielded false, while the template specialization based comparison yielded true. I tried it on clang (x86-64, v14.0.0) and both yield true.

I've heard that MSVC is terrible at the newer C++ stuff like templates and such, is that what's happening here? Does this count as a compiler bug? Is it worth reporting somewhere?

Comment: MSVS is treating `char thing[2]` as a `char * const` for some reason: https://godbolt.org/z/nGjE86cbz

Comment: @NathanOliver Aren't top-level qualifier discarded in function prototipes? I.e. shouldn't `void f(char*)` and `void f(char* const)` have the same type?

Comment: @paolo They should be discarded.  My surprise was more the appearance of the `const` in the first place.  the standard says array of T types are adjust to pointer to T types so that const shouldn't even be there to begin with.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand that. What makes this even more puzzling to me is: besides the `const` not having to be there, `void f(char*)` and `void f(char* const)` are not comparing equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this count as a compiler bug?

Yes, this seems to be a **msvc bug** which has been reported as:

[`type_info` yields incorrect result when comparing functions](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/type_info-yields-incorrect-result-when-c/10106483?).

The two functions do have the same type and the check `info == info2` should yield `true`.